# Dimension of linear systems of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am doing exercises of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry. In chapter IV, Ex. 1.5:

For a effective divisor $D$ on a curve $X$ of genus $g$, show that $\dim|D| \leq \deg D$.

I found a solution says: if $D$ is effective, then $\ell(K-D) \leq \ell(K)$ (here, $K$ is the canonical divisor).

Does anyone know why this is true? Is $|K-D| \subset |K|$ also true? Thanks.

Comment: There is an injective map $H^0(X,K-D) \rightarrow H^0(X,K)$ given by tensoring by any nonzero section of $O_X(D)$.

Comment: Notice that effective divisors of degree d on X are parametrized by the d-fold symmetric power X^(d) of X,  Since for D of degree d, the series |D| is a subvariety of this d- dimensional manifold, the result follows.  This point of view may not be available for this exercise, but I recommend it for maximum insight on linear systems.  For your actual question, compare the space of sections of the canonical bundle, to the subspace of those sections which vanish on the divisor D, and relate these spaces to those in your question. as in the previous comment.

Comment: Excellent comment, dear @roy smith !